# Is TestFX compatible with Java 13?

Tags: java, maven, javafx, testfx

I'm currently using **OpenJDK 13**, **JavaFx 14e-ea+2**, **testfx-junit 4.0.16-alpha** and **testfx-core 4.0.15-alpha**
I updated both from 8 and now the testfx tests are giving errors.
The errors are:

- `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'org.testfx.internal.JavaVersionAdapter$JavaVersion org.testfx.internal.JavaVersionAdapter.currentVersion()'`
- ````
  java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space ```
  ````

Is this testfx version compatible with the most updated javafx and jdk?

Comment: Even though TestFX is "recommanded" on the OpenJFX page, it does not seem to be actively maintained...